# How to control meteor's package version solver? Wrong jQuery version loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm really confused by the meteor package version solver. (using meteor 1.4.3)

In my .meteor/package file I specified
jquery@=1.11.10

which is also included in .meteor/versions and in .meteor/local/plugin-cache/jquery there is 1.11.10

However, when I run the app, bootstrap complains about that it requires a jquery version >= 1.9.1 and < 3 .... and the jquery version that has been loaded is the current 3.2.1 (as specified in $.fn.jquery).

How can this be?

Is there a why to dump information why the package solver chooses which version?

And where is the format documented how I can specified applicable version?
I found https://docs.meteor.com/api/packagejs.html#PackageAPI-use but there are only some examples listed, it seems not like a complete description of the syntax.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue by deleting node_modules/jquery ...

However, the questions remain
- what is the best way to debug the resolver for modules & packages ...
- why did it choose the wrong version. (Is this a mismatch of meteor and npm?)